# addEventListener - is there a more efficient way

Tags: javascript, events

I am adding JavaScript to alert users they need to fill out the specified fields. It's not the code that is wrong, but as I have two forms, and each field requires separate JavaScript, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way off writing the script? I know there is the required attribute you can write in the HTML, but I am not interested in that.

```
function prepareEventHandlers () {
document.getElementById("bookingFrm").addEventListener("submit",           function(event) {
        // Show message
        if (document.getElementById("email").value == "Your Email") {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please provide an email address!";
            // to STOP the form from submitting
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting // when using addEventListener, return false wont work, in all other cases use return false
        } else {
            // reset and allow the form to submit
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }  

});
}

  function prepareEventHandlersName () {
document.getElementById("bookingFrm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        // Show message
        if (document.getElementById("name").value == "Your Name") {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage1").innerHTML = "Please provide a name!";
            // to STOP the form from submitting
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting
        } else {
            // reset and allow the form to submit
            document.getElementById("errorMessage1").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }          
});
}

function start() {
  prepareEventHandlers();
  prepareEventHandlersName();
}
window.onload = start;
```

Comment: Why not check both name and email in the same function?

Comment: to respond on any event you have to attach your callback via addEventListener() or using event property smth.onsubmit = function(){...}

Comment: Why not use a validation library? Or at least look at one to see how it works.

Comment: Cheers for the advice guys and I will have a look now @Mathletics. Cheers for the code Sergey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do both checks within the same function?

```
function prepareEventHandlersForBoth () {
document.getElementById("bookingFrm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        // Show message
        if (document.getElementById("email").value == "Your Email") {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please provide an email address!";            
            event.preventDefault(); 
        } else {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }  
        if (document.getElementById("name").value == "Your Name") {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage1").innerHTML = "Please provide a name!";
            event.preventDefault(); 
        } else {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage1").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }         
});
}

}

function start() {
  prepareEventHandlersForBoth();
}
window.onload = start;
```